# swagger codegen spring boot missing XmlRootElement and XmlElement

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I use the following command to generate spring boot code using swagger

```
java -jar ./swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate \
        -i /swagger.yaml \
        -o ./swagger-demo-restful \
        -l spring
```

using the following definitions in swagger.yaml:

```
definitions:
  AlertDef:
    type: object
    properties:
      alertName:
        type: string
        description: name of the alert
        xml:
          name: AlertName
```

The generated code is like:

```
package io.swagger.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

/**
 * AlertDef
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2016-11-10T13:06:05.500+08:00")

public class AlertDef   {
  private String alertName = null;

  public AlertDef alertName(String alertName) {
    this.alertName = alertName;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * name of the alert
   * @return alertName
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "name of the alert")
  public String getAlertName() {
    return alertName;
  }

  public void setAlertName(String alertName) {
    this.alertName = alertName;
  }
  // toString, hashcode, etc...
}
```

But to make the restful API return XML successfully, it is needed to add `@XmlRootElement(name = "AlertDef")` to class and `@XmlElement` to each set method.

Is there something missing in the yaml file or swagger codegen doesn't support it for now?

Comment: Please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new. (you may also want to try the latest master to see if the issue has already been addressed)

Comment: will try it later